# asp.net server redirect causing Not Found [CFN #0005]

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .htaccess, redirect, web-config

So I've built a very small form website using asp.net and visual studio express 2015. The site works fine locally so far - but when I push everything to the hosted site it doesn't work.

The issue I currently have is the page is redirecting to a non-file extension page which results in the `Not Found [CFN #0005]` error message. So when going to `www.mysiteexample.com/mainpage.aspx` in the browser it is redirecting to `www.mysiteexample.com/mainpage` - and since there is no file named just 'mainpage' it is returning the not found error.

I've looked in a lot of places to try to find out why this is an issue - are there rewrite rules to put in web.config? Nothing seems to have worked. Should there be entries in the .htaccess file? Does there need to be some kind of configuration change on the server - which would require the hosting company to make? (by the way, the hosting company is saying its strictly a code issue and won't help).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Look at your hosting for help. Maybe they think you want MVC and automatically remove extension.

Comment: Wanted to provide an udpate that hosting site gave me details to route to different IP as the site was a hybrid site.  Losing ability to do SSL and PHP but that's not an issue in my case - at least yet.  My other option is to re-build using MVC I guess.  Thanks for the help!